# Problem of setting up a python app

Tags: python, django-haystack

Hey guys
I'm new to Python, I want to install this python app called [mirosubs](https://github.com/8planes/mirosubs) on my VPS, and I followed the installation guide in this github pages, when I got to the step 8:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I got the following error:

```
root@makserver:/usr/local/src/mirosubs# python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 35, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError haystack: cannot import name Thumbnail
```

Anybody can tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `haystack` is trying to import a type called `Thumbnail` but can't find it. Do a search through the source for `Thumbnail` and try to determine what's happening.

Comment: I think haystack and thumbnail both was installed correctly, I don't know much about python, and I've no idea what's wrong with the source code

Comment: @yoz, without actually downloading the source myself and looking at the code, I'm not going to be able to help any further. Try to look over the install directions and see if anything was missed. Looking at the requirements.txt file, ensure that sorl-thumbnail-3.2.5.tar.gz has been installed correctly.